# issue using plugin in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am trying to write an IOS in html & javascript that can scan a bar code using phonegap build. I added the following row to the phonegap config.xml for the barcode reader plugin:

<
gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="1.1.0" />

in the listener for a button I have the following code from the plugin example:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(

             function (result) {
                 alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                     "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                     "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                     "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
             },
             function (error) {
                 alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
             }
         );
```

When I try to run the app and press the scan button I get the following error:

"Can't find variable: cordova"

Any help on what I missing would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: try replacing `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` with `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and got the following error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.barcodeScanner")"  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. 
The html file needs to include a reference to the file cordova.js as 
script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">

thanks